# How to clear "warning message" after selecting file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Please follow the instructions below:

**My View:**

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "file" })
    <div id="ErrorFile"></div>
    <br />
</div>
```

**My Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({ 
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.ErrorFile) {
              $("#ErrorFile").html('<span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span class="">* Required field.</span></span>');
            }
        }
     });
```

After selected a file, the message should disappear. It continues to show.

How can I hide or clean "id = File Error" after file selected?

Comment: Why are you not just using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File)` and decorating the property with `[Required]` so all this is handles out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.ErrorFile) {
                $("#ErrorFile").html('<span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span class="">* Required field.</span></span>');
            } else {
                $("#ErrorFile").html('');
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Here:

```
$(function(){
$("#File").change(function () {
    if($(this).value != ''){
        $("#ErrorFile").hide();
    }
});
});
```